# ROS Wiki Indexer

Tags: ros, meta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a public interface to all the information that the ROS Wiki indexes, other than [these pages](http://www.ros.org/browse/repo_list.php)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39049/ros-wiki-indexer/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check the information on the wiki macros:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/WikiMacros

They depend on static files that have to be generated regularly to not become outdated.
Also see the packages (well, the source as of now):
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdoc
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosorg

Both packages contribute to the wiki result, but the code and structure need refactoring. I might do that soon, Tully also has it on his todo list.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-07-20**:
+1 for the existence of the rosorg stacks. I'd like to play in a roswiki sandbox.